# xpra not working after upgrading debian

Tags: debian, x-server, xvfb, xpra

Once upon a time, I installed `xpra` and have been using it without problem.

Then my harddrive crashed. I installed a new identical one, and restored a `dd` image of 6 months ago (before I had installed `xpra`).

I did `apt-get install xpra` and got one from the repositories, but it would not start a server. I'm pretty sure I never added special repositories and it used to work.

So I did a series of `apt-get update` `apt-get upgrade` `apt-get dist-upgrade` `apt-get install xpra`. Still not working. I purged `xpra`, added the [winswitch repository](http://winswitch.org/downloads/debian-repository.html) as explained in [the xpra.org download section](http://xpra.org/), but it still doesn't work.

The thing I loved about `xpra` is that it just worked. But now I ended up doing a lot of googling, adding my user to all kinds of groups, up- and downgrading packages, and I still can't get it to work.

Can someone give me advice?

```
$ xpra start :2020
Entering daemon mode; any further errors will be reported to:
  /run/user/1000/xpra/:2020.log

$ cat /run/user/1000/xpra/:2020.log

X.Org X Server 1.19.0
Release Date: 2016-11-15
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux Redsandro 4.8.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.11-1 (2016-12-02) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=253cbc66-c252-4b50-a622-f30f324c6fff ro quiet
Build Date: 23 November 2016  07:20:23PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.0-2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/run/user/1000/xpra/Xorg.:2020.log", Time: Sat Dec 17 15:11:50 2016
(++) Using config file: "/etc/xpra/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.so: undefined symbol: ChangeWindowProperty
display :2020 failed:
could not connect to X server on display ':2020' after 3 seconds
2016-12-17 15:11:53,416 killing xvfb with pid 17971
2016-12-17 15:11:53,418 failed to kill xvfb process with pid 17971:
2016-12-17 15:11:53,418  [Errno 3] No such process
```

It seems to try `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` and `xvfb` and both fail.

Comment: You are a betatester while using testing repository, so report the bug! https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=xpra

Answer (score 0):

The dummy driver version does not match your Xorg server version:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.so: undefined symbol: ChangeWindowProperty
```

Make sure that your dummy driver package matches the ABI version of the Xorg package.